# R : Split a table to a lot of indexed tables (table_1, table_2 ...) without using a for loop

Tags: r, split, vectorization

Actually I have a table which I want to split into small tables, in order to number them following a specific condition. For example table_1 where table$class==1, table_2 where table$class==2 etc.
I want to avoid the repetition but without using a for loop since I have a big table.

Here is what I have tried

```r
tab_1 = tab[tab$bucket==1 & !is.na(tab$bucket),]
tab_2 = tab[tab$bucket==2 & !is.na(tab$bucket),]
tab_3 = tab[tab$bucket==3 & !is.na(tab$bucket),]
 .
 .
 .
tab_10 = tab[tab$bucket==10 & !is.na(tab$bucket),]
```

Comment: `split(tab, tab$bucket)`

Comment: @jogo's suggestion will return a list, which is probably what you should be using, if for some reason you really need table objects you can do `x <- split(tab, tab$bucket); names(x) <- paste0("tab_", names(x)); list2env(x)`, but think twice, it's usually much wiser to keep data structured in a list.